# gem install memcached fails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, memcached

On doing

```
gem install memcached
```

following error gets thrown.

```
....
....
checking for pod2man... /usr/bin/pod2man
./configure: line 22468: syntax error near unexpected token `sasl,,'
./configure: line 22468: `      AC_LIB_HAVE_LINKFLAGS(sasl,,'
make: *** [config.status] Error 2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I have already install libmemcached using

sudo yum install libmemcached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this issue trying to install the memcached gem on Amazon's AMI Linux.

I resolved it with installing both cyrus-sasl and cyrus-sasl-devel:

```
cyrus-sasl.i686 : The Cyrus SASL library
cyrus-sasl-devel.i686 : Files needed for developing applications with Cyrus SASL
```

as well as, and this is key:

```
gettext.i686 : GNU libraries and utilities for producing multi-lingual messages
gettext-devel.i686 : Development files for gettext
```

Once these were installed

```
sudo gem install memcached
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed memcached-1.3.5 
1 gem installed
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm in same trouble on centos 6.4. And try "yum install cyrus-sasl and cyrus-sasl-devel", then fix it.

Answer (score 18):

On Ubuntu, try doing:

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2

sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install memcache-client instead.

```
gem install memcache-client
```

and you will see this:

```
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for memcache-client-1.8.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for memcache-client-1.8.5...
```