# AWS bundle install error: Make sure that `gem install memcached -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, bundler

I'm unable to deploy my rails app to elastic beanstalk due to a bundle install error. Here's the full log:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

      /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
  checking for sasl/sasl.h... no
  Please install SASL to continue. The package is called libsasl2-dev on Ubuntu and cyrus-sasl on Gentoo.
  *** extconf.rb failed ***
  Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
  libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
  need configuration options.

  Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby

  extconf failed, exit code 1

  Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/memcached-1.8.0 for inspection.
  Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/memcached-1.8.0/gem_make.out
  An error occurred while installing memcached (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot
  continue.
  Make sure that `gem install memcached -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before bundling. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

I recently updated to ruby 2.1.5 though rvm (I was running ruby 2.0.0 before), which may be causing my problems?

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: It's on an aws ec2 t1.micro instance running linux, not on my local computer. Sorry If i didn't mention that.

Answer (score 3):

> It's on an aws ec2 t1.micro instance running linux

Assuming this is Amazon's linux distribution (a `yum` based distro), you can look at the error message and derive a solution.

> Please install SASL to continue. The package is called libsasl2-dev on Ubuntu

For Ubuntu you would use

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
```

For your OS, you will need to use `yum`. Not sure the exact package name but you can try

```
sudo yum search libsasl
```

and find some variant of `libsasl2-dev`. Afterwards just run

```
sudo yum install <package name>
```

Comment: This helped solve my problem. For anybody looking at this, just ssh into your ec2 instance and use "sudo yum install <package name>" for each one of the packages listed on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757237/gem-install-memcached-fails

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on EB, have you tried adding libsasl2-dev to the packages in your Elastic Beanstalk configuration file?